# place order issue in onepage checkout knockout js magento 2

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, place-order

By selecting an existing shipping address in the checkout I am not able to place an order.

[image]

Comment: The error tells you that the `getCode` function doesn't exist. So you should check it

Comment: @Jimmy can you guide me to find respective file.